# R -nested loops

Tags: r, loops, apply, mapply

I am trying to write a code to simulate 3D array of the size 4*16*10 where each cell contains 10*10 matrix

So far I did nested for loops but they are extremely slow. I want to replace them with apply or mapply functions.

```
M=10
N=10
c=2
n=seq(1, 4, by=1)
p=0.25
q=seq(1,0.25, by =-0.05)
ntrials = 10




for (i in 1:length(n)){
  for (j in 1:length(q)){
    for (k in 1:ntrials){
      plant_subm=matrix_plantsubm(M,N,c,n,p,q)

}
}
}
```

Here matrix_plantsubm is a function that generates 10*10 matrices. I need to obtain matrices for each choice of n and q and repeat this 10 times.

I am quite new to R and don't know how to improve my code. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `gamma = 6/((q - p)*n)` should probably be `gamma = 6 / ((j - p) * i)`? Are you just overwriting `plan_subm` each time?

Comment: @Axeman I just overwrite this function each time.

Comment: Ok... but then you only have the last iteration saved.

Comment: Can you show definition of `matrix_plantsubm()`? Actually none of the args that are passed into this function change in *any* of the `for` loop iterations. You never use iterators `i`, `j`, or `k` or the calculated `gamma`.

Comment: your biggest slowdown appears to be copying the entire structure on each iteration, which would grow in time complexity exponentially.  If you allocate the space before hand then using for loops probably won't be a significant slowdown from apply functions (which will preallocate space)

Comment: Also, it's doubtful that `mapply` etc. will be noticeably faster than your `for` loops. Basically, all you're doing is calling `matrix_plantsubm` 640 times. If that function is slow, it doesn't matter how you call it, running it 640 times will be slow. If you need your code to speed up, find the slow parts through profiling, and work on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Data (OP)

```
M=10
N=10
c=2
n=seq(1, 4, by=1)
p=0.25
q=seq(1,0.25, by =-0.05)
ntrials = 10
```

## Create parameters, pass along to function via `pmap`

This will create all of the combinations of values that you need

```
params <- expand.grid(
  trial = 1:10,
  M = M,
  N = N,
  c = c,
  n = n,
  p = p,
  q = q
) %>%
  as_tibble()

View(params)

# > nrow(params)
# [1] 640

# replace with your own, of course
my_madeup_function <-
  function(M, N, c, n, p, q) {
    matrix(data = rep(M * N + c - n * p * q, 100),
           nrow = 10,
           ncol = 10)
  }

# we use `purrr::pmap`, an apply-type function to pass all of the parameters (except for trials) to the function:

result <- tibble(matrix = pmap(select(params, -trial), my_madeup_function))
```

Bind the parameters and results in a nice summary:

```
summary <- bind_cols(params, result)
```

Let's take a look at the results:

```
    > summary
# A tibble: 640 x 8
   trial     M     N     c     n     p     q matrix              
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>              
 1     1    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 2     2    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 3     3    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 4     4    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 5     5    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 6     6    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 7     7    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 8     8    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
 9     9    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
10    10    10    10     2     1  0.25     1 <dbl[,10] [10 x 10]>
# ... with 630 more rows
```

We can select a specific one with something like:

```
summary %>%
  filter(trial == 8, n == 2, q == 0.5) %>%
  .$matrix %>% 
  .[[1]]
```

On my machine, `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` reported the run time at about 7 ms, but this was with my "dummy" function. Hope your function runs fast, too. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. One last question: how can I use those matrices from result tibble as an input for another function? Using [[? Thank you again

Comment: `purrr::map` would be good for this. As a simple example, let's add a column to `summary` that is the determinant of the matrix: `summary %>% mutate(det = map(matrix, determinant))`. (note: the matrices in my "toy" example are all singular). Alternatively, you can just compute the determinants by `summary$matrix %>% map(determinant)`. Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: But what if I run another made_up function that uses all matrices from `summary`? Can I set new parameters  as a `tibble` and  use `purrr::pmap`again?

Comment: Yes, just make sure the columns names of the tibble you pass to `pmap` are the arguments of your function (as before).